# c++ template casting with derived classes

Tags: c++, templates, solaris, derived-class

```
#include <vector>

struct A {int a;};
struct B : public A {char b;};

int main()
{
  B b;
  typedef std::pair<A*, A*> MyPair;
  std::vector<MyPair> v;
  v.push_back(std::make_pair(&b, &b)); //compiler error should be here(pair<B*,B*>)
  return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why this compiles (maybe somebody can kindly provide detailed explanation? Is it something related to name look-up?

Btw, on Solaris, SunStudio12 it doesn't compile: `error : formal argument x of type const std::pair<A*, A*> & in call to std::vector<std::pair<A*,A*> >::push_back(const std::pair<A*, A*> & ) is being passed std::pair<B*, B*>`

Comment: That struct template above isn't really doing much is it?

Comment: @BennyG: It heard about some trouble in the neighbourhood and decided to come and have a look.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`std::pair` has a constructor template:

```
template<class U, class V> pair(const pair<U, V> &p);
```

> "Effects: Initializes members from the corresponding members of the argument, performing implicit conversions as needed."  (C++03, 20.2.2/4)

Conversion from a derived class pointer to a base class pointer is implicit.

Comment: I'm not convinced, make_pair is a template function, which deducts types from arguments. Right?

Comment: Yes, and it makes a `std::pair(B*,B*)`. It then uses the above constructor to construct an `std::pair(A*,A*)` out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Because B is derived from A, the vector v will contain pointers to base class structures of the object b. therefore, you could access the members of A, i.e.

```
std::cout << v[0].first->a;
```

EDIT:
My mistake, as pointed out below, you can still cast to pointers of type B since the vector is of pointers, not objects, so no object slicing has occurred.

A call such as

```
std::cout << v[0].first->b;
```

will not compile since the elements in the vector are base class pointers and cannot point to derived class members without a cast, i.e.

```
 std::cout << static_cast<B*>(v[0].first)->b;
```

Also note that a dynamic cast, as in

```
std::cout << dynamic_cast<B*>(v[0].first)->b;
```

will not compile with the following error in gcc:

```
cast.cpp:14: error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘v.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = std::pair<A*, A*>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<A*, A*> >](0u)->std::pair<A*, A*>::first’ (of type struct A*’) to type struct B*’ (source type is not polymorphic)
```

Comment: The members of class B have not been lost, and the dynamic type of the objects pointed to is still B.  Members of B can still be accessed:  `static_cast<B*>(v[0].first)->b` (though in this case, a `dynamic_cast` would probably be preferable).

Comment: @tmatth: As James McNellis says, you can still access the derived class members via a cast. Maybe you're thinking of object slicing? That occurs only when using a vector of objects (`A`), not a vector of pointers (`A*`). In that case, yes, members of `B` will be silently discarded.

Comment: i edited to reflect your feedback, hopefully this clears it up.

Comment: The `dynamic_cast` fails because `A` is not a polymorphic type; you have to add a virtual function to `A`.